# How can I filter RDD with LabeledPoint?

Tags: python, pyspark

My intial RDD looks like :

```python
RDD_int.collect() = [("a", 0, LabeledPoint(0, f01, f02, ..., f0n)), ("a", 1, LabeledPoint(0, f11, f12, ..., f1n)), ..., ("a", m, LabeledPoint(0, fm1, fm2, ..., fmn))]
```

I try this operation:

```python
RDD.filter(lambda x : "LabeledPoint" in x[2])
```

It doesn't work.

I hope obtain this one :

```python
RDD.collect() = [LabeledPoint(0, f01, f02, ..., f0n), LabeledPoint(0, f11, f12, ..., f1n), ..., LabeledPoint(0, fm1, fm2, ..., fmn)]
```

How can I do that with .filter of pyspark ?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[RDD.filter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.filter.html) is used to remove elements *("rows")* from the rdd based on a filter condition.

You would want to [map](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.map.html) each element of the rdd so that out of the original tuple `(String, Integer, LabeledPoint)` only the third element (the `LabeledPoint`) is kept:

```python
rdd = rdd.map(lambda t: t[2])
```